# Any good MongoDB admin UI for MacOS with auth support?

Tags: mongodb

I've been using mViever for several months and it fitted me perfectly, however it doesn't support proper authentification (when mongod is launched with --auth parameter). So, now I'm trying to find any good replacement for MacOS with auth support.

Tried MongoHub, but it doesn't support most of common Mac hotkeys (even Enter doesn't work as submit), and by the way, it also has some bugs with authentification. To be shorter, which of these http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs to choose? I've tested some of them, but nothing really liked (except old good mViever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that's a typo and you are referring to [mViewer](https://github.com/Imaginea/mViewer).  As you can see here, it does support authentication:

http://imaginea.github.com/mViewer/0.9/pages/getting_started.html

There were issues with auth in 0.9.1, but they have been fixed.  See here:

https://github.com/Imaginea/mViewer/issues/75

For some reason, the 0.9.2 binaries are not available yet (even though the comment says October), but it's not too hard to build yourself:

```
git clone https://github.com/Imaginea/mViewer.git
cd mViewer
mvn clean package -Prelease -DskipTests
```

Once all that was finished, I took a look in the target folder:

```
cd target
ls mViewer-0.9.2.*
```

Here's my mViewer 0.9.2 session logged in with user "adam" to an auth enabled `mongod`:

[image: mViewer 0.9.2 with auth]

Answer (score 0):

I just released a minimalist mongodb data viewer for nodejs [github.com/marcdelalonde/mongo-viewer](https://github.com/marcdelalonde/mongo-viewer)

I have planned to add auth support very soon :)